# Calling from Python Rust function with kwargs fails

Tags: rust, pyo3

I am struggling to get `kwargs` to work. I understand that just like `#[args(args="*")]` is for `args`, `#[args(kwargs="**")]` is for `kwargs`.

However when I pack the following using `pyo3-pack` and try to call `test1` with any arguments I get the error `MyClass.test1()() takes at most 0 argument (1 given)`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#![feature(custom_attribute)]
#![feature(specialization)]

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::{PyDict, PyTuple};

#[pyclass]
struct MyClass {}

#[pymethods]
impl MyClass {
    #[staticmethod]
    #[args(kwargs = "**")]
    fn test1(kwargs: Option<&PyDict>) -> PyResult<()> {
        if let Some(kwargs) = kwargs {
            for kwarg in kwargs {
                println!("{:?}", kwarg);
            }
        } else {
            println!("kwargs is none");
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    #[staticmethod]
    #[args(args = "*")]
    fn test2(args: &PyTuple) -> PyResult<()> {
        for arg in args {
            println!("{:?}", arg);
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}


#[pymodule]
fn test123(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<MyClass>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure this is a bug in PyO3: [this check](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/blob/cd23574d8a4a331a72d5ead1b5086f193c273fd5/src/derive_utils.rs#L48-L57) seems to be adding `nkeywords` for no reason.  File a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/PyO3/pyo3/issues) and see what the maintainers say.